# Render Xaml Components in a MAUI Blazor app?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui

Is it possible to have like a DatePicker xaml component into the MAUI Blazor webview?
I have read about mobile blazor bindings but i'm confused it it's already part of MAUI Blazor or you still need to create a separated project and then target it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/

Comment: *" i'm confused it it's already part of MAUI Blazor"* - I don't think so. If it was, MS would update that doc link you found. Just follow the instructions in that link. Given Maui's preliminary state, and the sparse documentation, you might also want to spend time with Xamarin Forms. See [Xamarin Forms DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/datepicker), which includes a link to XForms samples. Get that XF DatePicker sample to run - then you can see how it should look, and see working xaml. Then try to add that to your Maui Blazor app.